# How do I code multiple object chained method calls to continue across multiple lines of code?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've come across a lot of examples of how to continue powershell script code across multiple lines for example, calling a method that passes multiple parameters using the "back tick" (`):

```
myMethod $arg1 `
   $arg2 `
   $arg3 `
   ...etc.
```

But what I want to do, is continue object method chain linking across multiple lines, for example, I want to break this up across multiple lines of code:

```
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
[ref]$e = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException
$ps.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn( "SqlServerCmdletSnapin100", $e ) | Out-Null
# This is ridiculous; how to I break the below code across multiple lines???
$ps.AddCommand( "Invoke-Sqlcmd").AddParameter( "InputFile", $PreCompareInfoObject.PreCompareBatchScript).AddParameter("serverinstance", $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestServer).AddParameter("database", $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestDB).AddParameter( "username", $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestUserName).AddParameter("password",  $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestPassword).AddParameter( "variable",  $variable).AddParameter("outputsqlerrors",  $true).AddParameter("abortonerror").AddParameter("Verbose") | out-file -filepath $PreCompareInfoObject.PreCompareOutputReport
$ps.Invoke()
```

I could do this, but I don't want to, and the output is more verbose than I'd like for some reason:

```
...
$ps.AddCommand( "Invoke-Sqlcmd")
$ps.AddParameter( "InputFile", $PreCompareInfoObject.PreCompareBatchScript)
$ps.AddParameter("serverinstance", $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestServer)
$ps.AddParameter("database", $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestDB)
$ps.AddParameter( "username", $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestUserName)
$ps.AddParameter("password",  $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestPassword)
$ps.AddParameter( "variable",  $variable)
$ps.AddParameter("outputsqlerrors",  $true)
$ps.AddParameter("abortonerror")
$ps.AddParameter("Verbose") | out-file -filepath $PreCompareInfoObject.PreCompareOutputReport
...
```

I guess I am looking to this, but of course, it doesn't work:

```
$ps `
   .AddCommand( "Invoke-Sqlcmd") `
   .AddParameter( "InputFile", $PreCompareInfoObject.PreCompareBatchScript) `
   .AddParameter("serverinstance", $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestServer) `
   .AddParameter("database", $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestDB) `
   .AddParameter( "username", $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestUserName)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your example should work- what error do you get?

Comment: Assuming the last example was possible the trailing spaces before the backticks should be removed.

Comment: Hey, did you get a chance to try my approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
$ps. 
 Addcommand("Invoke-SqlCmd"). 
 AddParameter("InputFile", $PreCompareInfoObject.PreCompareBatchScript).
```

etc

That is, end the line with the dot, and then you can continue on the next line, without using the backtick.

Comment: this doesn't work. I indicated I am using Powershell 2.0, what version are you using this on/testing this on?

Answer (score 0):

You could store all or most of your params in a hashtable, then call `GetEnumerator()` to return a list of key/value pairs, and run `ForEach-Object` to add them all to your `$ps`, if you'd like.  Here what that woudl look like.

```
$params = @{InputFile=$PreCompareInfoObject.PreCompareBatchScript
    "serverinstance"=$DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestServer
    "database"= $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestDB
     "username"= $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestUserName
    "password"=  $DBConnectInfoObject.DBDestPassword
     "variable"=  $variable
    "outputsqlerrors"= $true
    }

$params.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $ps.AddParameter($_.Key,$_.Value)
    }
```

I would still run your AddCommand() step on it's own line, but you should be to handle most, or all of your parameters with this approach.

Comment: this would work, but it's really doing nothing more than calling .AddParameter multiple times outside of a loop, but thank you.